# Tomcat 7 undeploy button disabled

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-manager

On my Tomcat Manager page, the undeploy button is disabled. Can any one help?

Tomcat: 7.0.23

JDK:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Linux:

```
2.4.21-58.EL （Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-59）
```

below is the html inside it

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2" class="row-left">
    <form action="/manager/html/start?path=/fxperf&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=6EBE01514D0EC24FED6D78DD915D9BCA" method="POST" class="inline">
        <small><input type="submit" value="Start"></small>
    </form>
    <small>Stop</small>
    <small>Reload</small>
    <small>Undeploy</small>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something wrong with application which you want to undeploy rather than JDK. Check your application.

Comment: Thx for comment. later I　 found out my server.xml is not correct respecting to this app part.

Comment: @hetaoblog how did you fixed it. what what the issue ?